# Как правильно запустить один ScrollRect внутри другого ScrollRect

Tags: gui, ui, unity3d

У меня есть вертикальное меню, а самый верхний уровень должен скролиться ещё и горизонтально. Но вот реально это работает так: вертикально скролится всё отлично, но только до верхнего уровня. Как только верхний уровень полностью закроет экран, скроллинг возможен только горизонтально - вертикально уже не получается вернуться.

[image: скриншот]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи только UI этого не сделать, так как дочерний `ScrollRect` "захватывает" события от средств ввода (то есть, при получении, например, клика мыши, он обрабатывает его сам и не отдает другим).

Нужно написать скрипт, который будет получать необходимые события и передавать их "родителям".

Скрипт для отлова событий должен реализовывать соответствующие интерфейсы. Для отлова перемещения понадобится реализовать как минимум `IInitializePotentialDragHandler`, `IBeginDragHandler`, `IDragHandler` и `IEndDragHandler`. Сам `ScrollRect` реализует и другие инерфейсы событий, их - по необходимости.

Текст скрипта:

```
namespace Utilities.UI
{
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

    // Простой маршрутизатор событий скролла.
    // Передает события перемещения ScrollRect родительским элементам UI.
    // Необходимо вешать на дочерний ScrollRect.
    [AddComponentMenu("Utilities/UI/Parent Scroll Router")]
    [RequireComponent(typeof(ScrollRect))]
    public class ParentScrollRouter : MonoBehaviour, IInitializePotentialDragHandler, IBeginDragHandler, IDragHandler, IEndDragHandler 
    {
        // Передаем родителям событие, которое отправляется перед возможным началом перемещения.
        public void OnInitializePotentialDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            var parent = transform.parent;
            while(parent != null) 
            {
                foreach(var handler in parent.GetComponents<IInitializePotentialDragHandler>())
                    handler.OnInitializePotentialDrag(eventData);

                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        }

        // Передаем родителям событие начала перемещения.
        public void OnBeginDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            var parent = transform.parent;
            while(parent != null) 
            {
                foreach(var handler in parent.GetComponents<IBeginDragHandler>())
                    handler.OnBeginDrag(eventData);

                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        }

        // Передаем родителям событие перемещения.
        public void OnDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            var parent = transform.parent;
            while(parent != null) 
            {
                foreach(var handler in parent.GetComponents<IDragHandler>())
                    handler.OnDrag(eventData);

                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        }

        // Передаем родителям событие завершения перемещения.
        public void OnEndDrag (PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            var parent = transform.parent;
            while(parent != null) 
            {
                foreach(var handler in parent.GetComponents<IEndDragHandler>())
                    handler.OnEndDrag(eventData);

                parent = parent.parent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Файл скрипта необходимо назвать `ParentScrollRouter`. Чтобы события приходили в скрипт, необходимо повесить его на `GameObject`  c дочерним `ScrollRect`. Для Вашего случая, дочернему `ScrollRect` нужно поставить галочку `Vertical`, а родительскому - `Horizontal`.

Comment: Володя, огромное спасибо за шикарный ответ! Лаконично, понятно, и, главное, ты объясняешь причины, почему так нужно делать. Я тебе очень признателен. Вообще, как ты умудряешься настолько глубоко раскапывать такие тонкие вещи? (Прости, сходу перешёл на "ты" - ничего?) Да, я могу прислать скриншот для закрепления понимания, но у меня не получается прикрепить рисунок. Как это делается-то?

Comment: Пожалуйста, рад, что помог. Как умудряюсь раскапывать: тематический опыт гугления + знание английского, ну и опыт программирования, чтобы найденное осознать и применить. Да и в данном случае не так уж глубоко я копнул. Скриншот здесь можно вставить при помощи кнопки в тулбаре при редактировании поста, либо со стороннего сервиса в виде HTML `<img src="http://example.com/img.jpg">` или Markdown  `![некое изображение](http://example.com/img.jpg)`. При низкой репутации что-то  из этого может быть недоступно.

Comment: Для меня проще на диск залить... Вот ссылка: https://yadi.sk/i/FkwBjOmpjhF7C

Comment: Добавил скриншот. Если ответ помог - можно отметить его решением, это галочка слева.

Comment: Володя, приветствую! А ты бы мог посоветовать какую-то информацию, чтобы последовательно освоить тонкости Юнити? Например, что ты сам читаешь, чтобы так прекрасно во всём этом разбираться? (А то я начал новый проект, но, возможно, есть техники гораздо более эффективные, чем те, которыми я пользуюсь). Мне подойдёт и на английском информация - для меня важна структура обучения, последовательность и глубина. Прости, если надоел расспросами...

Comment: @СергейНетягин Я сам в основном использую [официальный сайт, (доки, форум, Q&A)](http://unity3d.com/ru/learn), но ищу обычно через гугл в виде "unity what I need". А на английском по Unity выходит огромное кол-во книг. В гугле "unity 5 books": например, целая серия по Unity 5: [1](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/getting-started-unity-5), [2](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/unity-3d-gui-essentials), [3](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/unity-animation-essentials), [4](https://www.packtpub.com/game-development/building-levels-unity) и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо, прекрасно! Я сам на это внимания как-то не обращал. Обязательно возьму на вооружение. Большое спасибо. Успехов тебе!